# Synchronizing with a server in a Android app

Tags: android, synchronization

I'm developing a app that requires sync with the server app every 5 minutes... Which is the best way to accomplish that? I'm using a ThreadPoolExecutor (java way...) but I'm not very happy with that... and I want to know what other solutions can you provide me....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can use **Thread, [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** with time interval of 5 minutes, or just use a background [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which execute web-service at every 5 minutes continuously.

Also Use `AlarmManager` to set up your schedule and an `IntentService` to do the actual work. The `IntentService` automatically gives you your background thread for your network I/O, and it automatically shuts down the service when the work is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to wake up your app (service or whatever) every 5 minutes to perform the operation.

Some examples:

1. It wakes CPU every 10 minutes until the phone turns off: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)
2. Using AlarmManager to Schedule Activities on Android: http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129

Answer (score 1):

I favour alarm manager / broadcast receiver solution  with non-wakeup alarms.  Updating information from webservice seldom makes sense for slleping phones ( as there is no user present to react or notice changes ) - thus you can save traffic and  power